# Shutter image export error: Error while connecting

Tags: shutter

I get the following error during exporting the image to **Imgur Guest** or **ImmIO Guest. (Throws same error for all Guest upload servers)**

**Error while connecting**

`malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/upload_plugins/upload/Minus.pm line 145.`

Please see the screen shot below
[image]

Comment: This really is a bug report. I'm happy there's a listed workaround below, but I'd like to see this cross referenced with a bug so we can correct the ubuntu packaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wintermute seems to be right, it's just broken (as of now). However, [in the link he provided](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/1565048), there seems to be a patch.

What you need to do is download the "Imgur.patch" file, and put it next to "Imgur.pm" found in:

```
/usr/share/shutter/resources/system/upload_plugins/upload/
```

Then go to that directory in your terminal, then run

```
sudo patch Imgur.pm Imgur.patch
```

This should use the .patch file to patch Imgur.pm. If it goes over well, the console should just output "patching file Imgur.pm" and nothing else.

Comment: This worked, Thanks.  
$ sudo patch Imgur.pm ~/Imgur.patch 
patching file Imgur.pm
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #3 succeeded at 101 with fuzz 1.

Answer (score 3):

Imgur guest upload is currently [broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/1565048). You can use alternatives like [Imgur-Screenshot](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/take-screenshots-and-upload-to-imgur.html) until it's fixed.

Comment: not only imgur, other guest sites are also throwing same error.